# wordpress sidebar highlight active link on scroll and click

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I created a custom menu and added it to the page's default sidebar. 
That custom menu has links to anchor pages on a single main page. Each one of these links have their own custom css class (.feat1 , .feat2).

I'm trying to change the links color based on the current url.
I'll navigate (by scrolling or clicking) through /url/portfolio/#feat1 , /url/portfolio/#feat2, etc.

I tried a lot of CSS code and the nearest thing I could get was this

```
#nav_menu-2 .feat1 a:focus{
    color: #f00;
    background: #ff0;
}
//did this for .feat2 too
```

This change and keeps a new color when I click one of those links but it wont change to the new link when I scroll to the next page.

I tried the same code with **a:active** and from what I read it should be the right code to do what I want since it actually (should) change based on the current url but at this moment it does not detect when the url changes on scroll and it only changes the link color on the click time-frame (getting back to the default color after this).

I also tried using "current-menu-item" for the #sidebar class:

```
#sidebar .current-menu-item a:active{
    color: #f00;
    background: #ff0;
}
```

Same as using individual classes, "active" only changes the color on the click moment, then when it sends you to the anchor page the link is back to default.

Any idea of what could be wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

CSS `:active` and `:focus` do not respond to scroll events by themselves. If you want to adjust the highlights based on scroll position you will need to monitor the scroll position using `window.onscroll` event listener. When the scroll height is within the range corresponding to your section, you can assign a class to the navigation element which should be highlighted.

There are libraries that can assist in this. The common name used by various libraries is `scrollspy`.

Some libraries:

- http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/
- http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy

If you implement it yourself in pure JavaScript, I recommend wrapping your event handler in a `debounce` function. This can prevent your handler from firing too frequently which can cause unnecessary CPU/battery consumption and make the scrolling motion jumpy.

jQuery/Waypoints example:

```
$("h2").waypoint(function(direction){
  $("#nav-menu a").removeClass("active");
  $("#nav-menu a[href='#" +this.element.id+"']").addClass("active");
});
```

Comment: I did something like this in the past using bootstrap on a webapp but this time I'm trying to make this work on wordpress without usning much code. I just want to make sure if there is any tool or method I could use here.
Thank you for clarifying me on the :active :focus part.

Comment: I use bootstrap in most of my WordPress themes, but as long as you have jQuery and load the Waypoints library, I'll a jQuery example to the answer.